# Would have find or found

Tags: word-choice, grammar, differences

A friend is looking for an apartment in a certain time in the future and she doubt if the owner would agree to renew her contract. So what do I say? Do I say "by the end of the contract you would have found/find another apartment to move in" please explain which is right.

Comment: "Would have found" is used to speak about unrealized actions in the past.

Answer (score 2):

"One would hope that by the end of the contract you will have ***found*** another apartment"